# Build cgicc-3.2.16 for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, cgi

I want to build cgicc-3.2.16 but it is NOT building. I have tried **cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 Win64** with Cmake through **VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt** but that didn't work.

I am getting the error below :

**CMake Error: The source directory "D:/Webserver/cgicc-3.2.16/cgicc" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.**

I checked in that directory and cMakeLists.txt is actually not there. I have been building libraries without problems but this one did not come with the cMakeLists.text.

Any **instruction** or **help** on how to build this(**cgicc-3.2.16**) for **Windows** would be appreciated.

Comment: "Didn't work" -- you'll go far in this field. In the mean time voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to build this. For anyone else having thesame problem, here is how you can build it:

When **cgicc** is downloaded, there is a **folder** name called **win**. **Open** the **folder** and you will find a **file** called **cgicc.dsp**. **Open** that file and visual studio will open. You can then press the Build button. Make sure you change it from Debug to Release. Easy as that!